A doGet script passes the current users' email to a form. The forms' embedded script is triggered by onOPen. How can it retrieve the email?
This is the script for doGet:
function doGet(e) {
     const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

     if (!email) {
       return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Access Denied</h1><p>You must be      signed in to access this form.</p>');
     }

     const preFilledFormUrl = generatePreFilledFormUrl(email);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>Google Form</h1>
        <p>Benvenuto, ${email}</p>
        <iframe src="${preFilledFormUrl}" width="100%" height="800"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
}

function generatePreFilledFormUrl(email) {
  const formUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSepCWXuUFt3oKXBlsLWBurnSl_vuleGAu6gSIKr87bT3vOAaA/viewform";
  const fieldKey = "entry.335126256";                        // this is the ID of the form item "email"
  return `${formUrl}?${fieldKey}=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`;
}

google automatically inserted a new item into the form. The new item has the correct email of the invoking user (not necessarily my email):
enter image description here
My first question: is it possible to retrieve the value for this item (the email)?
Second Question/Problem.
The form item with id = 335126256 (as specified in the URL passed by doGet) is not prefilled with the email address. A getResponse check shows no value for the item:
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
const formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (let i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  const formResponse = formResponses[i];
  const itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (let j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    const itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    Logger.log(
      'Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
      (i + 1).toString(),
      itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
      itemResponse.getResponse(),
    );
  }
}

Any ideas why? Is there any other way to get the passed email?
Thanks

Do not post two questions in one post. Questions here need to be super focused on one issue and one issue only.

Form RespondentEmail
Sample Code
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
const formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (let i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  const formResponse = formResponses[i];
  console.log(formResponses[i].getRespondentEmail())
  const itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  for (let j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    const itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
    Logger.log(
        'Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
        (i + 1).toString(),
        itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
        itemResponse.getResponse(),
    );
  }
}

What you need is to get Respondent Email in your case, please check the code above for the changes I made.
Reference:
getRespondentEmail

Unfortunately I am now receiving the error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRespondentEmail'). Could this be because I am trying to get the email in an onOpen before the form is submitted? The Google documentation for Class FormResponse states that " For a form response that the script has created but not yet submitted, this method returns null."

Yes that is correct. Since at the start there is still no response yet.

I just console log it since I have no Idea.What is your next step. I answered this first because I do think that it affects the next step of your project. If you have further questions please post it as another question.
